# how does $scope in controllers work and different ways of declaring controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I am looking at some samples of how controllers work in angular and I see two ways of declaring them, one with just controller name and one with "as somename". Examples that use ng-controller = "myController" take a $scope as dependency when defining controller.
Then model is then set on the $scope, something like this

```
 $scope.mymodel = somevalue;
```

Example that uses "as" syntax such as ng-controller = "MyControler as vm" never uses $scope when setting up the model but ratther assigns it to "this" and binds using {{vm.something}}.

in controller:

```
var vm =this;

vm.something = somevalue;
```

How is that working in second example? Is that new way in latest version?

Comment: `as` is different than using `this` in controller. Recent changes allowed using `this` instead of `$scope` in controller. `as` is used in markup

Comment: Here's a nice 5 minute video that lines up nicely with your question: http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-experimental-controller-as-syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "as" syntax exposes your entire controller to your view. In my opinion, that is a bad practice. Although I'm not sure which one is better performance wise, but using 'this' in javascript already has plenty of issues of its own, and I don't recommend adding another meaning to 'this'. So I would stick to $scope (since that is what they're using in the docs as well).
See this topic if you want to know more context about how the 'as' syntax work: ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)